# how to fit xib view width to superView width

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a xib view like this ,and its width is 728px now.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNpaa.png)

[iamge2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z62xV.png)

I apply it into my mainView like this (my mainView's width is 1024px),but its width doesn't fit my main view's width.

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0bs1.png)

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcMlu.png)

[image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuhY8.png)

what should I do? anyone can help me?

**code**

```
class common: UIView {
    // コードから呼び出す際に使用される
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadNib()
    }

    // Storyboardから利用する際に使用される
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadNib()
    }

    // 上記どちらのinitからも使用される共通関数で、xibファイルを呼び出す。
    func loadNib() {
        // 第1引数のnameには、xibファイル名
        // ownerはself固定
        // optionsはここではnil
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("common", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code, how you have loaded the .xib into your main view?

Answer (score 1):

In your .xib file, give IBOutlet to view like this:

[image]

IBOutlet:

```
 @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
```

You need to add `autoresizingMask` to the view you are loading.
Here, see the change in code.

Try below code for the resizing:

```
 func loadNib() {
               Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("common", owner: self, options: nil)
       addSubview(contentView)
       contentView.frame = self.bounds
       contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }
```

Comment: still not work. Maybe it's because I set the width of the subview in the xib?

Comment: I change the xib view to stackView and it work. thank you so much